# Swift: Parse database doesn't update object

Tags: swift, database, parse-platform

I'm building an app and I need a connection with a database. I'm using Parse for this (and hosting it with back4app if that does matter).
I have already a lot of experience with Parse so it's very weird that I have this problem.

So I need to update an object but it doesn't. Could somebody please help me out? I've putted in my code an print and it does print so you know the app get's there but strangely enough, it doesn't update the object.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: the code works because when I run the app in the simulator it updates but when I run it on my iPhone, it doens't?**

```
func makeMessagesSeen() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Chat")
    query.whereKey("senderID", equalTo: otherID)
    query.whereKey("receiverID", equalTo: yourID)
    query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
    var objects = try! query.findObjects()

    for i in objects {
        if (objects[0].objectId == i.objectId) {
            print("this will print , idk why code beneath this doesn't work?")
            i["messageSeen"] = "last seen"
            i.saveInBackground()
        }
        else {
            i["messageSeen"] = "seen"
            i.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to print `objects[0]` and `i`? They might be NULL. Also, are you sure `query.findObjects()` is not blocking your main thread?

Comment: It wasn't NULL, it also didn't block the main thread. I found the solution, it was a bad mistake of me but I posted the solution as an answer. Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and will post the solution here in case anyone will make the same mistake.

So I created the message object with my simulator and parse automatically set the write acces for everyone to false. Only for the device that created the message it was set to true. So that's why I could only update to object with my simulator.

So change in your database the write acces for everyone to true.